# How to upload a movie file in Django?

Tags: django, file-upload

I am sorry if this question is already posted somewhere.

I am very new to Django. I have been googling around for quite a long time for sample codes to upload large files using Django, but goes in vain.

Can anyone help me with some sample code for uploading large files in Django or provide relavant reliable link(s)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django itself handles large files uploads quite well (the whole file is not loaded to memory since 1.0, see http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2070).

But django usually sits behind web server and there is often a limit over request body. So Web server config should be probably adjusted (if you are using apache, look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody ).

Answer (score 0):

There is this called [django-video](https://github.com/andrewebdev/django-video). I haven't tried it though. I have used [django-basic-apps](https://github.com/montylounge/django-basic-apps)
 which can handle video, music and image uploads.