# Video uploads to S3 via Django-based API

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, tastypie

I'm creating a simple API hosted on heroku for handling video uploads from remote clients (mobile applications) currently consuming data from a Django-based API.

I need the video filename/URL to be both obscure and unique.

I could take several approaches:

1) Ask the Django-based API to give me a unique and obscure filename, upload the video directly to S3 with that filename, then post an upload status update to the API.

2) Upload the video directly to S3 from mobile app, send a request to the API with video details, which then spawns a task to rename the video filename on S3 and update the video url attribute in my Django model.

3) Post the video directly to the API, which would handle naming the file and uploading to S3.

In the possible case that I'll need to process the video before uploading to S3 in the future, the first and second approaches would require the server to download the video that has already been uploaded to S3, process it and then re-upload to S3.

What would the recommended architecture in this case be?

Comment: https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple design options.

1. If you upload directly to S3 prior to processing, here is a good article on using python to directly upload to your bucket:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python

   You'd want a separate task server (or Lambda) to trigger a separate job to handle your video processing.  This way your website remains unencumbered and fast.  You'll want to utilize a queue (SQS in AWS) for scale.
2. Alternatively, your web server can do all the work: the download, processing and s3 upload.

   - Django handles video uploads well: [How to upload a movie file in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953999/how-to-upload-a-movie-file-in-django)
   - OpenCV for video processing?
   - boto for uploads:
     http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/python/

The second approach is more straightforward, but won't handle web server load as well, it will also be more expensive to scale.

I suggest the first approach which allows s3 to handle your upload, Lambda and a SQS to handle your processing, and your web server remains light.  A bit more development as its not linear, but should be cheaper to scale and provide better performance and response time to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is useful. I've updated the question to slant more towards an architecture recommendation request, rather a particular technology, since it's been put on hold.